# Print text from any number of combo boxes

Tags: python, combobox, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to print text from combo box(es) whenever the text in the combo box changes. I'm able to print text from a combo box whenever I know the name of the combo box, but the way my code is currently set up, whenever I add a new row with a new combo box, I am unable to print the text since I don't know what the name of the combo box is. For example, if I add 4 rows, I don't know what the name of the combo box in row 4 is.

In my code below, every time I add a new row, I'm able to add a combo box to that column. Col1 demonstrates this. In Col2, I demonstrate how I print the combo box text whenever it changes. So, how can I continue adding combo boxes every time I add a new row, but also print the text any time any of the combo boxes change?

Eventually, whenever the text in a combo box changes, I want to populate the other columns for that row based on a lookup using pandas. The first step I believe is figuring out when the text changes for any given combo box.

GUI Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'test.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(568, 359)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 531, 311))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_1.setObjectName("tab_1")
        self.add_tab_1_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_1)
        self.add_tab_1_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 113, 32))
        self.add_tab_1_button.setObjectName("add_tab_1_button")
        self.tab_1_table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab_1)
        self.tab_1_table.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 1180, 230))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.tab_1_table.setFont(font)
        self.tab_1_table.setAutoScrollMargin(16)
        self.tab_1_table.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.tab_1_table.setColumnCount(5)
        self.tab_1_table.setObjectName("tab_1_table")
        self.tab_1_table.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tab_1_table.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tab_1_table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tab_1_table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tab_1_table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tab_1_table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tab_1_table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(195, 200, 200))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        item.setBackground(brush)
        item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        self.tab_1_table.setItem(0, 4, item)
        self.tab_1_table.horizontalHeader().setCascadingSectionResizes(False)
        self.tab_1_table.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(100)
        self.tab_1_table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.tab_1_table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tab_1_table.verticalHeader().setHighlightSections(True)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_1)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 0, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_1, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tab_2_table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab_2)
        self.tab_2_table.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 1180, 230))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.tab_2_table.setFont(font)
        self.tab_2_table.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.tab_2_table.setColumnCount(5)
        self.tab_2_table.setObjectName("tab_2_table")
        self.tab_2_table.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tab_2_table.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tab_2_table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tab_2_table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tab_2_table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tab_2_table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tab_2_table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        self.tab_2_table.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(100)
        self.tab_2_table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.add_tab_2_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.add_tab_2_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 113, 32))
        self.add_tab_2_button.setObjectName("add_tab_2_button")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 568, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionNew = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionNew.setObjectName("actionNew")
        self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")
        self.actionExport_Recipe = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExport_Recipe.setObjectName("actionExport_Recipe")
        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionNew)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionExport_Recipe)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionExit)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Calculator"))
        self.add_tab_1_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add Row"))
        item = self.tab_1_table.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tab_1_table.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Col1"))
        item = self.tab_1_table.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Col2"))
        item = self.tab_1_table.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Col3"))
        item = self.tab_1_table.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Col4"))
        item = self.tab_1_table.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Col5"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tab_1_table.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tab_1_table.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.tab_1_table.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_1), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab1"))
        item = self.tab_2_table.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tab_2_table.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Col1"))
        item = self.tab_2_table.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Col2"))
        item = self.tab_2_table.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Col3"))
        item = self.tab_2_table.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Col4"))
        item = self.tab_2_table.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Col5"))
        self.add_tab_2_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add Row"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab2"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.actionNew.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New..."))
        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Import Recipe..."))
        self.actionExport_Recipe.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Export Recipe..."))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Python Code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from test import Ui_MainWindow
import pandas as pd


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Create combo box for Col1
        combo_box_1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox() 
        combo_box_1.addItems(['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'])
        self.ui.tab_1_table.setCellWidget(0, 0, combo_box_1) 

        # Connect add row buttons to functions
        self.ui.add_tab_1_button.clicked.connect(self.add_row)

        ### Test section ###
        # Create combo box for Col2
        self.combo_box_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.ui.tab_1_table.setCellWidget(0, 1, self.combo_box_2)
        self.combo_box_2.addItems(['Item A', 'Item B', 'Item C'])
        self.combo_box_2.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.print_selected_text)
        ##################

    def add_row(self):
        """Add row and insert combo box in column.."""

        rowPos = self.ui.tab_1_table.rowCount()

        # Create new instance of a combo boxes
        new_combo_box_1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox() 
        new_combo_box_1.addItems(['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'])

        # Insert new row and add combo boxes
        self.ui.tab_1_table.insertRow(rowPos)
        self.ui.tab_1_table.setCellWidget(rowPos, 0, new_combo_box_1) 

    def print_selected_text(self):
        """Test function to see if cell text will be printed whenever it changes."""
        print(self.combo_box_2.currentText())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QComboBox has a signal `currentTextChanged` which is sent whenever its `currentText` is changed. It automatically passes the new text to whatever slot you connect it with.

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.combo_box_2.currentTextChanged[str].connect(self.print_selected_text)

def add_row(self):
    ...
    new_combo_box_1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox() 
    new_combo_box_1.addItems(['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'])
    new_combo_box_1.currentTextChanged[str].connect(self.print_selected_text)
    ...

def print_selected_text(self, text):
    print(text)
```

You can check out the other signals [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#signals) which can eliminate the need of a pointer to the object.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! When I was reading the currentTextChanged prior to posting, I didn't realize I could do this. One question - why did you add [str]? Is it because anything in a combo box is considered a string, and that is accessing whatever string is currently displayed in the combo box?

Comment: Some signals are overloaded so you can ensure the kind of object passed with the [type] syntax. For example, I believe `currentIndexChanged` has an `[int]` and a `[str]` version.

Comment: @Simon1 while there's technically nothing wrong with specifying the signature for signals that don't have overloads, it's completely unnecessary; you should ignore that in these cases (which are the majority), and just use the basic signal.